# count client_id from tbl_appointment_book using join in php

Tags: mysql

I have two table. I want count client_id from `tbl_appointment_book` but `tbl_appointment_book`'s `id` and `tbl_appointment_service`'s `appointment_id` should be match.

**tbl_appointment_book**

```
id appointment_date client_id status
1  2016-05-11         1         1
2  2016-05-12         1         1
```

**tbl_appointment_service**

```
id appointment_id service_id team_id

1   1               1          1
2   1               2          1
3   1               8          5
4   2               1          1
5   2               1          2
```

I want to count `client_id` from `tbl_appointment_book` condition
`appointment_date=2016-05-11, team_id=1`

Comment: Please show your table definitions and the SQL you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query, it should work fine.

```
SELECT COUNT (tab.client_id)
FROM tbl_appointment_book tab
JOIN tbl_appointment_service tas
ON tab.id = tas.appointment_id
WHERE tab.appointment_date = '2016-05-11' AND tas.team_id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JOIN` to achieve your wanted result:

```
SELECT count(a.client_id) FROM tbl_appointment_book a
                          JOIN tbl_appointment_service b
                              ON a.id = b.appointment_id
                          WHERE a.appointment_date = '2016-05-11' AND b.team_id = 1
```

Result will be the number of rows returned.